# Poetry install fails with EnvCommandError: looks for version 2020.12.21.3-lambda, why?

Tags: python, pip, python-poetry

Poetry cannot complete any `install` or `add` without throwing an `EnvCommandError` having to do with not being able to find a `setup.py` for `soupsieve`.

It looks for version "2020.12.21.3-lambda" and I don't understand why it's not loading the dependency from a remote source with a normal version like the other dependencies.

```
$ poetry update
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (54.1s)

Writing lock file

Package operations: 59 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing soupsieve (2020.12.21.3-lambda): Failed

  EnvCommandError

  Command ['/home/git/my-project/.venv/bin/pip', 'install', '--no-deps', 'file:///home/Library/Caches/pypoetry/artifacts/22/36/ca/c8aae41f80011be881aa337cc80abc25ffd8542471c325e4410afa86c8/authorities-deployer-2020.12.21.3-lambda.zip'] errored with the following return code 1, and output: 
 Looking in indexes: ... # censored proxy
  Processing /home/Library/Caches/pypoetry/artifacts/22/36/ca/c8aae41f80011be881aa337cc80abc25ffd8542471c325e4410afa86c8/authorities-deployer-2020.12.21.3-lambda.zip
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /home/git/my-package/my-package/.venv/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/q6/xjd92kc90zsds149_rx08cy40000gp/T/pip-req-build-40kngare/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/q6/xjd92kc90zsds149_rx08cy40000gp/T/pip-req-build-40kngare/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/q6/xjd92kc90zsds149_rx08cy40000gp/T/pip-pip-egg-info-02b8jxuf
           cwd: /private/var/folders/q6/xjd92kc90zsds149_rx08cy40000gp/T/pip-req-build-40kngare/
      Complete output (5 lines):
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
        File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tokenize.py", line 392, in open
          buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
      FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/private/var/folders/q6/xjd92kc90zsds149_rx08cy40000gp/T/pip-req-build-40kngare/setup.py'
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  WARNING: You are using pip version 20.3.1; however, version 20.3.3 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the '/home/git/my-package/my-package/.venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
  

  at ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/utils/env.py:1074 in _run
      1070│                 output = subprocess.check_output(
      1071│                     cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, **kwargs
      1072│                 )
      1073│         except CalledProcessError as e:
    → 1074│             raise EnvCommandError(e, input=input_)
      1075│ 
      1076│         return decode(output)
      1077│ 
      1078│     def execute(self, bin, *args, **kwargs):
```

This package has worked just fine for some time. I don't remember changing anything in the `pyproject.toml`. **I tried checking out an old version of `pyproject.toml` to see if maybe something had changed accidentally.** Same result.

**I also tried deleting the `.venv/` Poetry creates and recreating it.** Same result.

I have no idea where `soupsieve` is coming as a dependency. It installs just fine using plain old pip inside the environment poetry creates.

```
cd project/
poetry shell
pip install soupsieve # Installs 2.1 without a problem
```

Comment: Did you try to remove poetry cache? `poetry cache clear . --all`

Comment: Yes. Did not work. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I had this same error because for some reason `poetry install` always failed to create a virtual enviroment path in `%APPDATA%`. The solution was to move the venv to the local project root.

```
poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true
poetry env remove python
poetry install
```

Answer (score 2):

### Quick fix

So the root problem had nothing to do with `poetry`, but I was able to at least unblock myself from this issue by explicitly adding the sub-dependency with a specific version.

```
pip add soupsieve==2.1
```

### Root problem

The real problem was that our systems proxy everything through a private artifact repository that had been poisoned with bad metadata: it contained things named `soupsieve` that were not actually `soupsieve`.

Once we removed these things, `poetry` went back to working well.

Comment: We got a similar issue with corrupted artifact and solved it by removing the artifact itself from the cache system where it complained (in your case: /home/Library/Caches/pypoetry/artifacts/22/36/ca/c8aae41f80011be881aa337cc80abc25ffd8542471c325e4410afa86c8/authorities-deployer-2020.12.21.3-lambda.zip)

Comment: Yes. Exactly what we had to do.