# Poetry install fails during docker build with CalledProcessError and EnvCommandError

Tags: docker, pypi, python-poetry

## Problem summary

I've been trying to build a docker image which installs dependencies using poetry command `RUN poetry install`. 
I am doing it as part of `docker build` job of the GitLab CI/CD pipeline, running it on the own runner VM instance. 
However, docker build process repeatedly crashes during `poetry install` run with `CalledProcessError`, and then, during handling of this error, with `EnvCommandError` and `PoetryException` errors. 
Few sample errors are below:

```
 CalledProcessError
 Command '['/home/ray/anaconda3/bin/python', '/home/ray/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/virtualenv/seed/wheels/embed/pip-22.0.4-py3-none-any.whl/pip', 'install', '--disable-pip-version-check', '--prefix', '/home/ray/anaconda3', '--no-deps', '/home/ray/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/a8/b9/10/d38e9304d486f9398ab4163054bd6af79c74073ad8685d6cc67f88eccc/Werkzeug-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Then

```
EnvCommandError
Command ['/home/ray/anaconda3/bin/python', '/home/ray/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/virtualenv/seed/wheels/embed/pip-22.0.4-py3-none-any.whl/pip', 'install', '--disable-pip-version-check', '--prefix', '/home/ray/anaconda3', '--no-deps', '/home/ray/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/a8/b9/10/d38e9304d486f9398ab4163054bd6af79c74073ad8685d6cc67f88eccc/Werkzeug-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl'] errored with the following return code 1, and output: 
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -irtualenv (/home/ray/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages)
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ray/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/virtualenv/seed/wheels/embed/pip-22.0.4-py3-none-any.whl'
```

Then also `PoetryException` error:

```
PoetryException
Failed to install /home/ray/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/a8/b9/10/d38e9304d486f9398ab4163054bd6af79c74073ad8685d6cc67f88eccc/Werkzeug-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl
at anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/poetry/utils/pip.py:55 in pip_install
```

Same series of errors happen for `Werkzeug-2.2.2` (listed above) and for `torch-1.11.0` (not listed to spare space).

## Attempts to resolve

I tried the following without success:

- Cleaning PyPI cache as described [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/pypi_repository/#troubleshooting) by adding command `pip cache purge` to my docker file or before building docker image.
- I wanted to somehow follow the suggestion from **Quick Fix** described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65783409/poetry-install-fails-with-envcommanderror-looks-for-version-2020-12-21-3-lambda). However, I cannot locate those artifacts `/home/ray/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/a8/b9/10/d38e9304d486f9398ab4163054bd6af79c74073ad8685d6cc67f88eccc/Werkzeug-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl`. So I don't understand how to delete them.

I can share the docker file, if needed.

I will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

```
RUN pip install -U pip virtualenv
```

Poetry gets and cache path to `pip` wheel on startup from `virtualenv` package with `virtualenv.seed.wheels.embed.get_embed_wheel`. Looks like `virtualenv` can be update while `poetry install` is running and this path become invalid.

Comment: Thank you so much, adding the proposed command helped!